# SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell) does not see hidden cells

Tags: vba, excel

I try to unhide columns using this:

```
Range(Target, Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

Only columns `A` and `B` in the sheet are visible, others - hidden, although there are values entered in `A:K`. `Target` can be any cell in column `A` (this is a snippet from an event code).

How to unhide cells?

Comment: Can you pls explain further what you are trying to do?

Comment: Well, I was trying to unhide columns, but only those which are actually used (`A:K`)- `UsedRange` or `xlCellTypeLastCell` should work for that. First I tried the latter, but obviously that does not work and I don't know why.When I debug, I see that `xlCellTypeLastCell` refers to a cell in `B` column. However, I have achieved what I wanted by employing `UsedRange` which does not ignore hidden columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved what I wanted by employing `UsedRange` which does not ignore hidden columns. The code could be:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```

I actually used this (as the code is in a worksheet module):

```
Me.UsedRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
```